# can anybody tell me the re expression for split the string-->('(A) gre (B)Toefl (C)PET (D)CET') to a list ['gre','Toefl','PET','CET']

Tags: python, python-re

Can anybody tell me the re expression for splitting  the string:

```
('(A) gre (B)Toefl (C)PET (D)CET')
```

to a list:

```
['gre','Toefl','PET','CET']
```

using Python?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Can you provide more general information about the possible input strings? For example: can the terms you are looking for be more than single words? Can they include non-letters? Conversely, can the terms be given in a different order (e.g. `'(B) bar (A) foo'`)? Can there be more than one parenthesized marker (e.g. `'(A)(B) kidding'`)? Etc. Without a description of the specs, we are just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture anything -- except an opening parenthesis -- after a closing parenthesis, trimmed:

```
s = '(A) an example (B) next point (C)CAPS, lowercase! (D)CET'
result = re.findall(r"\)\s*([^(]*)(?<! )", s)
```

`result` will be:

```
['an example', 'next point', 'CAPS, lowercase!', 'CET']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `re.findall` approach here:

```py
inp = "(A) gre (B)Toefl (C)PET (D)CET"
matches = re.findall(r'\([A-Z]+\)\s*(\w+)', inp)
print(matches)  # ['gre', 'Toefl', 'PET', 'CET']
```